# JavaScript DOM Parser incompatível com document?

Tags: javascript, dom

A minha ideia com o `DOM Parser` era carregar uns layouts em HTML, colocar em um único elemento e depois usar quando necessário. Mas nos testes, o objeto gerado por `DOMParser` não é adicionado ao document. Veja o exemplo que fiz no JSFIddle:

HTML:

```
<div id="resHtml">
</div>
<div id="resDOM">
</div>
<div id="resXML">
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
var txt = '<fieldset><legend>Em texto HTML</legend><p>Alguma coisa a dizer</p></fieldset>';
document.getElementById("resHtml").innerHTML = txt;
// Simples, mas aí tenho que já ter em texto, e não dentro de um XML.
var domDoc = document.createElement('fieldset');
var domLegend = document.createElement('legend');
domLegend.innerHTML = 'Em DOM';
var domTexto = document.createElement('p');
domTexto.innerHTML = 'Alguma coisa a dizer';
domDoc.appendChild(domLegend);
domDoc.appendChild(domTexto);
document.getElementById("resDOM").appendChild(domDoc);
// Esse é construído peça por peça, não serve, mas ilustra o appendChild
var str = '<fieldset><legend>Em XML</legend><p>Alguma coisa a dizer</p></fieldset>';
var parser = new DOMParser();
var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(str,"text/xml");
//document.getElementById("resXML").appendChild(xmlDoc); NÃO FUNCIONA!
// É um exemplo simples, mas posso ter por exemplo uma coleção de formulários em um XML e pegar só que eu preciso adicionando por appendChild.
// Mas não funciona, então é o seguinte...
document.getElementById("resXML").innerHTML = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xmlDoc);
```

No final, tenho que serializar, o que pode até deixar uma página lenta, dependendo da encrenca.

No MDN Mozilla ([Referência](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)) ele está como experimental, então minha pergunta é a seguinte: esse API será algum dia compatível, devemos investir nele, ou existe uma diferença fundamental entre os objetos que teremos que ter sempre em mente?

Comment: Tenta .appendChild(xmlDoc.documentElement)

Comment: Aparece só os textos, sem as tags - texto desformatado. Mas valeu o palpite, já é alguma coisa...

Comment: Explica um pouco melhor como você quer usar esse XML na vida real.

Comment: Por exemplo: estou desenvolvendo um site que usa vários formulários. Eu diagramo eles todos em uma página separada, identificando por ID ou por name mesmo. Depois carrego a página em uma variável via xmlhttprequest e busco o formulário que eu preciso dentro desta variável conforme a necessidade - os formulários ficam todos disponíveis. Melhor que uma página para cada um que tem que carregar toda a vez que precisa.